# windows.location.reload() only one time in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi all I have following code:

```
     const [firstRender, setFirstRender] = useState(true);

      const refreshPage = () => {
         window.location.reload();
      };

       useEffect(() => {
        if (firstRender) {
          refreshPage();
         setFirstRender(false);
        }
       }, [firstRender]);
```

What I am trying to do is when the user enter page `useEffect` should trigger and reload page.

So every time when user enter the page first it should reload and then user can do what he/she want.

But after refreshing `firstRender` is always becoming `true` and I getting infinity refreshing call.

So please me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Because, every time after the refresh, react state starts from `0` again so in your case, it is always true.

IMO, there is something wrong with the approach you are taking, But, if you still need to achieve this, consider using `sessionStorage/localStorage` browser API.

Comment: Can you please provide some code with `sessionStorage/localStorage` for my case? ... thanks )

Comment: In your case `useState(true);` will be determined by the state saved in `local/session` storage. I hope it helps!